# How to programmatically clear PaperInput and have the floating label drop down to the input line

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, material-design

I have the following markup:

```dart
<paper-input id="alias-input" floatingLabel label="Person Alias (eg: King, Eldest Son, Mooch, etc.)"></paper-input>
<paper-input id="birth-year-input" floatingLabel label="Birth Year (eg: 1969)" validate="^[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"></paper-input>

<div center horizontal layout>
  <paper-button id="add-button" on-click="{{addPerson}}" class="add" label="Add Person"></paper-button>
</div>
```

To go along with this markup I have an *addButton* method which does:

```dart
addPerson(_) {
  // Add the person
  // ...

  // Clear the inputs
  ($['alias-input'] as PaperInput)..inputValue = ''..commit()..blur();
  ($['birth-year-input'] as PaperInput)..inputValue = ''..commit()..blur();
}
```

This correctly clears the contents of the inputs, which I want. But I also want the PaperInput help label to drop down onto the line as it is when the control is first loaded. My hope was that the call to *blur()* would do that. Is there some other call to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to call `blur` on the actual `<input id='input'>` element inside `<paper-input>` not the `<paper-input>` itself.
I got it working with

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
```

```dart
var inp = $['alias-input'] as PaperInput;
inp.inputValue = '';
new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(inp).callMethod('inputBlurAction', []);
```

alternatively you can do it like

```dart
var inp = $['alias-input'] as PaperInput;
inp.inputValue = '';
inp.querySelector('* /deep/ #input') // not yet supported with polyfills
..focus() // blur doesn't work when the field doesn't have the focus
..blur();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work:

    _($['alias-input'] as PaperInput)..inputValue = null..commit()..blur();_

had the same effect as setting it to _''_.