# How can you programmatically disable/hide just the CoreTooltip from core-elements?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, core-elements

Is there a way to dynamically hide a *core-tooltip*?
In general I want the tooltip turned off. However, if it is determined that the *content* element requiring the tooltip has clearly invalid data I want to see the tooltip.

For example:

```dart
    <core-tooltip position="bottom" label="Name can not already be present">
      <paper-input floatingLabel
                   id="alias-input"
                   type="text"
                   label="Enter Name"
                   >
      </paper-input>
    </core-tooltip>
```

I am trying to use this instead of the *error* attribute of *PaperInput*. In this case, on entry the input field has no contents so the *label* should be enough of a hint, so I do not want the tooltip displayed. But, if they enter a name that is already being used I'd like to only then display the tooltip. I can determine if the name in the *paper-input* is being used by looking in a map while listening to *onKeyUp*. But then how can I turn off the tip if it is not present?

If I set style *display:none* the arrow head and minuscule of body of an empty tip still shows.

I'm simply looking for a way to *disable*/*enable* a CoreTooltip.

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a way using the component's api. This seems to work:

First select the CoreTooltip in the code. To enable that you can add an id to the *core-tooltip*

```dart
    <core-tooltip id="cttp" position="bottom" label="Name can not already be present">
      <paper-input floatingLabel
                   id="alias-input"
                   type="text"
                   label="Enter Name"
                   >
      </paper-input>
    </core-tooltip>
```

Then use Gunter's approach of grabbing internal elements using querySelector with */deep/* (See also [How to programmatically clear PaperInput and have the floating label drop down to the input line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671906/how-to-programmatically-clear-paperinput-and-have-the-floating-label-drop-down-t))

```dart
    final ttip = $['cttp'].querySelector('* /deep/ #tooltip');
    (ttip as DivElement).style.display = 'none';
```

The trick is knowing how to select just the *tip* of the *core-tooltip* and then hiding it. Not sure the best way to determine this, by trying to study the code of *core-tooltip* or drilling down into *#shadowDom* instances in inspector of the tooltips to find the actual element you're trying to hide. In this case the actual tip div kindly had an id of *tooltip* to query on. Not sure this is a good strategy in terms of encapsulation, though.

Answer (score 3):

A CSS solution.

I bound it to the `invalid` attribute just for demonstration purposes.

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_tooltip.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">

<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }

      core-tooltip[hide="true"]:focus::shadow .polymer-tooltip,
      core-tooltip[hide="true"]:hover::shadow .polymer-tooltip {
        visibility: hidden !important;
      }
    </style>
    <core-tooltip position="bottom" label="Name can not already be present" hide="{{!isValidationError}}" >
      <paper-input floatingLabel
                   id="alias-input"
                   type="text"
                   label="Enter Name"
                   required invalid="{{isValidationError}}"
          >
      </paper-input>
      <span>isError: {{isValidationError}}</span>
    </core-tooltip>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="app_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('app-element')

class AppElement extends PolymerElement {

  AppElement.created() : super.created() {  }

  @PublishedProperty(reflect: true) bool isValidationError;
}
```