# How can I focus a CoreInput in Dart?

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer

Apparently, the CoreInput element in Polymer is still awaiting support for .focus() and .blur(), and there's a workaround in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24496827/1286442

What's the Dart equivalent, so that I might focus my core-input?

Comment: See the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671906

Comment: Thanks Günter. I guess my issue now is: as I have template if around my core-input, it's not loaded into $ initially, so I have to use querySelector but as it's several elements deep into the page it's hard to get at. I can't use /deep/ as that has no support on e.g. Safari. I get the idea, though, and will continue exploring. These kinds of issues are what I find most annoying w/ Polymer.

Comment: "but as it's several elements deep into the page it's hard to get at": this implies you are breaking encapsulation, which is a bad idea in general. "I can't use /deep/ as that has no support on e.g. Safari": the polyfill provides this support for you.

Comment: @ScottMiles, I have my-app > item-view > item-activities, and in there is my core-input. Not sure which part's the "bad idea"? Re: /deep/, last I'd checked that was not supported on Safari (I'd get null). I'm using Dart and that's post-build if that matters.

Comment: From my-app's perspective, item-view should be providing whatever API you need, and should be ignorant of item-view's internals. As I said, outside of Chrome, the ShadowDOM Polyfill provides /deep/ support in querySelector. I refer only to the JS code, but I'm surprised if Dart is different in this way.

Comment: As far as I know `/deep/` was added very recently and Dart is always a bit behind JS.